# Is it possible to use 80 bit floats with MSVC compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point

I am using Visual Studio with the MSVC compiler. Basically any other compiler seems to support native 80 bit floats of x86/x64 CPUs, except MSVC. It seems that a workaround would be using inline assembler, but apparently MSVC does also not support this in 64 bit mode.

Is there some possibility to make use of the 80-bit-float-capabilities of my CPU with MSCV? Performance would have highest priority, so any software solution is out of the question. Portability is not an issue since I would only use my code on Windows x64 machines.

Comment: From memory, only 16-bit (i.e. older versions) of MSVC supported use of the native floating point types.  32-bit and 64-bit compilers do not - not even as a non-standard extension or option.       If you want to use the native (80 bit) types, you'll need to resort to another compiler that does support them (as an extension) - such as gcc.

Comment: @Peter – _Small niggle:_ When type `long double` is implemented as an 80-bit float, the [C++ Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-12) describes it as a _standard_ type, rather than an _extended_ type: "The types `float`, `double`, and `long double`, and cv-qualified versions ([basic.type.qualifier]) thereof, are collectively termed _standard floating-point types_." Thus, it is not an extension. Rather, it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @tbxfreeware   Yeah sure.  But my basic comment stands (and I've since checked).   Only MSVC 16-bit compilers supported use of 80-bit floating point types.  The 32-bit and 64-bit MSVC compilers (to date, I can't predict future evolution of MSVC) do not support 80-bit floating point *at all* - not as a standard floating point type, not via a configuration option, and not via some non-standard extension.

Comment: Sorry. My statement was not clear. I was referring to the second part of your statement: _you'll need to resort to another compiler that does support them (as an extension) - such as gcc._ When gcc implements type `long double` as an 80-bit float, that is not an _extension_, it is a _detail of the implementation._ Like I said: it's a small niggle.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use 80 bit floats with MSVC compiler?

Unfortunately, the answer is "no."

From day one, we are all taught that the underlying types used by *standard types*, such as `int`, `long long int`, and `long double`, are *implementation specific*. We are warned that the implementation could change, even between two versions of the same compiler. Back in the 1980's, for instance, Microsoft implemented `int` as a 16-bit type, as it should have. Back then, Intel's microprocessors had a 16-bit word size. Later, when processors evolved, Microsoft switched to a 32-bit `int`.

Today, unfortunately, Microsoft has seemingly frozen its type definitions. Even where the hardware supports it, Microsoft won't give us 128-bit integers and 80-bit floats (or bigger).

##### Support for inline assembler

> A workaround would be using inline assembler, but apparently MSVC does also not support this in 64 bit mode.

Right. While MSVC's x86 mode still has support for inline assembler, [x64 does not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=msvc-170). The reason given is that inline assembler interferes with optimization, and also that many of the uses of inline assembler can now be accomplished with [compiler intrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/compiler-intrinsics?view=msvc-170). The latter applies to things like SSE, but won't help you with 80-bit floats.

Searching around the interwebs, I did find a suggestion to write your own `.asm` modules, rather than use inline assembler. That would be doable for simple math operations, but that won't get you the full complement of functions found in `<cmath>`. Microsoft has those functions, but explains in this [Microsoft Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/floating-point-support?view=msvc-170), "The compiler treats long double and double as distinct types, but the long double functions are identical to their double counterparts."

##### At one time, Microsoft had 80-bit floats

Thanks to @Pete Becker for pointing out (in a comment below) that Microsoft once had support for 80-bit floats, but dropped it in the changeover to NT in 1993. I have not checked, but I believe that is the same time that Microsoft switched to 32-bit ints. At the time, Microsoft's justification was the one that Pete details: NT targeted a variety of processors, some of which did not have support for 80-bit floats.

In 2006, Ronald Laeremans, Acting Product Unit Manager for the Visual C++ Team, added another reason, saying in a [post at CodeGuru](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?390950-RESOLVED-When-is-80bit-long-double-coming-back&p=1410439#post1410439):

> There are no current plans to add 80 bit FP support.
>
> The major reason is that FP code generation has been switching to the use of SSE/SSE2/SSE3 instruction sets instead of the x87 FP stack since that is what both the AMD and Intel recent and future chip generations are focusing their performance efforts on. These instruction sets only support 32 and 64 bit FP formats.

Comment: So there isn't even a possibility to use inline assembler (which I have never used and basically know nothing about) to create sort of a custom datatype?

Comment: Back in the olden days, MSVC's `long double` was 80 bits. Then, with Windows NT, they got cross-platform religion and decided that that mandated 64 bits.

Comment: I wonder why they don't even bother declare a switch that allows using 80bit version. Alignment is  obviously one concern; in 32bit code, proper alignment would require 2 padding bytes, in 64bit design, the waste would increase to 6 bytes. Although setting alignment as 2 in 64bit can totally remove the padding; because either way 2 memory access are needed, and a shift/rotate would fit the value in place.